# Aggregating array of values in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, json, elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to aggregate an array as follows

Two document examples:

```
{
    "_index": "log",
    "_type": "travels",
    "_id": "tnQsGy4lS0K6uT3Hwzzo-g",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "state": "saopaulo",
        "date": "2014-10-30T17",
        "traveler": "patrick",
        "registry": "123123",
        "cities": {
            "saopaulo": 1,
            "riodejaneiro": 2,
            "total": 2
        },
        "reasons": [
            "Entrega de encomenda"
        ],
        "from": [
            "CompraRapida"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "log",
    "_type": "travels",
    "_id": "tnQsGy4lS0K6uT3Hwzzo-g",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "state": "saopaulo",
        "date": "2014-10-31T17",
        "traveler": "patrick",
        "registry": "123123",
        "cities": {
            "saopaulo": 1,
            "curitiba": 1,
            "total": 2
        },
        "reasons": [
            "Entrega de encomenda"
        ],
        "from": [
            "CompraRapida"
        ]
    }
},
```

I want to aggregate the `cities` array, to find out all the `cities` the `traveler` has gone to. I want something like this:

```
{
    "traveler":{
        "name":"patrick"
    },
    "cities":{
        "saopaulo":2,
        "riodejaneiro":2,
        "curitiba":1,
        "total":3
    }
}
```

Where the `total` is the length of the `cities` array minus 1. I tried the terms aggregation and the sum, but couldn't output the desired output.

Changes in the document structure can be made, so if anything like that would help me, I'd be pleased to know.

Comment: Do you have a mapping for that index that you can share?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in the document posted above "***cities***" is not a json array , it is a json object.
If changing the document structure is a possibility I would change cities in the document to be an array of object

**example document:**

```
 cities : [
   {
     "name" :"saopaulo"
     "visit_count" :"2",

   },
   {
     "name" :"riodejaneiro"
     "visit_count" :"1",

   }
]
```

You would then need to set cities to be of type [nested](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping) in the index mapping

```
   "mappings": {
         "<type_name>": {
            "properties": {
               "cities": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "city": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "count": {
                        "type": "integer"
                     },
                     "value": {
                        "type": "long"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "date": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "registry": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "state": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "traveler": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

After which  you could use [nested aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) to get the city count per user.
The query would look something on these lines :

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "traveler": "patrick"
      }
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "city_travelled": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "cities"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "citycount": {
               "cardinality": {
                  "field": "cities.city"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this double count "saopaulo", since I visited it on day 30 and day 31?

Comment: @PatrickVillela yeah i misunderstood the question i edited the answer using cardinality http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html  gives the total count of the distinct cities  as wanted however one would have to subtact the -1 to account for total,probably total shouldn't be a part of "cities" object/field anyways and be a separate field outside

Comment: Hello. Sorry for my delay, but I had to design a solution for another problem. I may return to this one  later this week. I think it might work, though...