# Group by term and get list of array keys and their count

Tags: elasticsearch

in elasticsearch i got several hundred thousand documents with roughly this kind of structure:

```
{
  "script": "/index.html",
  "query": {
    "ab": "hello",
    "cd": "world",
    "ef": "123"
}
```

The url "http://localhost/index.html?ab=hello&cd=world&ef=123" is parsed into it. "script" only contains the path and the target script - no query at all.
The query array does not contain the same list of keys and of course different values, which doesn't matter at the moment at all.

I know, i am able to get a distinct list of "script" with:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "script.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which results into multiple buckets like

```
"buckets": [
{
    "key": "/index.html",
    "doc_count": 123456
},
{
    "key": "/hello.html",
    "doc_count": 1456
},
...
```

My question: Is there a way to get additionally a list and count of all query **keys**, which are occurring in the different urls?

Something like:

```
"buckets": [
{
    "key": "/index.html",
    "doc_count": 123456,
    "query_key_count": {
      "ab": 33456,
      "cd": 3456,
      "ef": 456,
      "gh": 56,
      "ij": 6
    }
},
{
    "key": "/hello.html",
    "doc_count": 1456,
    "query_key_count": {
      "zy": 156,
      "gh": 6
    }
},
...
```

Thanks alot!!

Comment: You mean, the *query_key_count* actually contains the number of occurrences of its keys among all items in your data. Say if you have 10 total objects, with 2 objects having "ab" in their *query* object, then you want the result to be *query_key_count*:{"ab":2 ... so on so forth}?

Comment: This should help you >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743204/aggregating-array-of-values-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Yes, if i have a index.html-doc with the params "ab" and "cd" and another index.html-doc with the params "cd" and "ef" with random values, i like to get a "query_key_count":{"cd": 2, "ab": 1, "ef": 1}.
Thanks alot for the link - i will have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To leverage Elasticsearch's strengths, you really need your documents to be structured something like this:

```
{
   "script": "/index.html",
   "query": [
      {
         "query_key": "ab",
         "query_val": "hello"
      },
      {
         "query_key": "cd",
         "query_val": "world"
      },
      {
         "query_key": "ef",
         "query_val": "123"
      }
   ]
}
```

If I set up a mapping with a [nested type](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html):

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "query": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "query_key": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "query_val": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            },
            "script": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and add a couple of docs:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"script": "/index.html","query": [{"query_key":"ab", "query_val":"hello"},{"query_key":"cd", "query_val":"world"}, {"query_key":"ef", "query_val":"123"}]}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"script": "/index.html","query": [{"query_key":"ab", "query_val":"foo"},{"query_key":"cd", "query_val":"bar"}, {"query_key":"gh", "query_val":"456"}]}
```

I can get back query keys in a [nested](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) terms aggregation:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "resellers": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "query"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "query_keys": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "query.query_key"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "resellers": {
         "doc_count": 6,
         "query_keys": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "ab",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "cd",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "ef",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "gh",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/aecd92e5903f644e28c802860a90a86bdd7f97ee

Comment: That did it - thanks a million!
In addition to my question your request is missing the first grouping by the script itself. I changed your request to:

 { "aggs": { "group_by_script": { "terms": { "field": "script" }, "aggs": { "query_count": { "nested": { "path": "query" }, "aggs": { "query_keys": { "terms": { "field": "query.query_key" } } } } } } } }

Now it is perfectly working :)